# Class-table inheritance without flag column

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to implement proper [Class Table Inheritance (aka Table Per Type Inheritance)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html) in mySQL.

AFAIK it's not offered out of the box so some hacking around is needed to make it tick.

---

#### Current situation:

Here's my example schema:

[image: mySQL ERD with a <code>Customer</code> parent table and 2 "child tables" connected by referencing <code>idCustomer</code> which is the primary key on "parent table". The child tables are <code>CustomerPerson</code> and <code>CustomerOrganization</code>]

To break this down:

- `Customer` is the parent table which contains common fields for all *Customers*.
- `CustomerPerson/CustomerOrganization` are child tables and contain all fields of `Customer` + the specific ones depending whether *Customer* is *Organization* or *Person*.
- I'm using a flag (column `type` on `Customer`) to differentiate between *Person* or *Organization*.

  - If I'm not mistaken, that "flag" would be called a *discriminator* in this context.

#### The problem.

- > I think having a flag/discriminator column on Customer is **not the ideal** and another table needs to be added, e.g `CustomerType` which connects the child tables with the parent tables.
- > Do I need another table or am I overthinking this? If yes how should I connect them?

---

**Notes:**

- The above example works just fine but I'd like to hear ideas on how to do this in the best way possible.
- Best-way possible is meant in terms of scalability and DRY-ness. Having a `type` column on every table that deals with this differentiation will just make things more messy as time passes and the schema gets more complex.

Comment: You don't need a type column. Hibernate doesn't use one, for example. You can figure out the type from the table. You're probably better off w Single Table Inheritance though, as it's faster and simpler, and works better with other tools (like Hibernate, Jackson, Spring Data)

Comment: Classes and objects did not exist until decades after SQL was well established.  I think "inheritance" does not fit will with SQL.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I already considered & rejected Single-table inheritance as it won't allow me to enforce `NOT NULL` columns which are really important here. Also adding new *Customer Types* won't be really a breeze. - On the first part of your comment can you expand on it in an answer?

Comment: @RickJames I don't think it really matters which one came first. If you think there's a better, more SQL-y way of modelling what I'm trying to do feel free to post it an answer.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides you can use check constraints in other dbs, but yes, it's a problem in mysql.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Isn't there a way I can use another table, perhaps `CustomerTypes` that will allow me to do what I want?

Comment: @RickJames SQL: Early 70s, OOP: mid 60s (Simula). Table Inheritance is required for concepts like the Party Model, which is highly useful